# Facebook Graph API determine if Video is Boosted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a quick way using the graph api to determine if a video has been boosted (paid advertising)?  I currently have an App which is used to automatically crosspost videos, but I run into an issue where FB doesn't allow you to continue crossposting the video once the video has been boosted.  It's locking out the ability to edit the video.  I kind of see this as a bug but that's not what I'm after here.  I can account for this if I can determine if the video has been boosted, but I'm not seeing an easy way to determine this.  Maybe through insights and see if there are paid views?  Or maybe through the Marketing API?  Is there a flag or something that tells me this info on the video itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went tried a number of solutions by looking at video insights, post promotion_status and none of them accurately matched how FB is determining the video is boosted and locked from being edited.

The solution I came up with is to making a pointless update to the video.  If the graph api fails to update the video and returns an error subcode of 1363005 (API v5.0), the video is Locked out from being edited and you can no longer crosspost this video.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Graph API Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post) and check for the `promotion_status` field:

> `promotion_status`: Status of the promotion, if the post was promoted

You can retrieve the same field also on the [page Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/page/feed)

Hope this help

Comment: So I see that field is available for the Post API, but not the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/ Video API.  When a video is boosted, does that create a Post which is linked to the video id?  If so, then again I'm not seeing that connection through the Video API, only the Post API with the `object_id` field.  Is there a way to quickly search with the Post API to find this connection?